# setTimeout in React implicitly outputs numbers to the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, settimeout

I am trying to implement a delayed typing animation in React, which when started, removes the placeholder text. My attempt to do so, has been by setting state after a timeout, and then render the animation and remove the placeholder when the state is true.

However, using setTimeout outputs some 'random' numbers in its container, and I have not been able to figure out why - I assume that the numbers rendered is the time in milliseconds for the timeout, they only change a few times before stopping.

The output can be seen here:

[image]

And an example of the entire component can be seen here:

[image]

Essentially I am trying to animate a chat correspondence, and need to render a div looking like an input field. The div has a default placeholder text which needs to be removed after xxxx milliseconds after which the Typist text is rendered displaying the typing animation.

The Chat component depicted below uses a number state as well as a function to increase the number. The number state is used to identify which chat bubbles have already been rendered, since the bubbles have an animation callback which is where the state is being changed - to ensure that the next chat bubble does not start animating in, until the prior one is completely done.

The problem is that I need a timeout to occur when the 'input field' is rendered, since the user has to see the placeholder for a couple of seconds before the typing animation from Typist is triggered.

**Chat.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import ChatBubble from './ChatBubble/ChatBubble';
import classes from './Chat.module.css';
import ScrollAnimation from 'react-animate-on-scroll';
import Typist from 'react-typist';

const Chat = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const [showInputText, setShowInputText] = useState(false);

  const choices = [{ text: 'Under 2 år siden' }, { text: 'Over 2 år siden' }];

  const choices2 = [{ text: 'Ja' }, { text: 'Nej' }];

  const typistCursor = {
    hideWhenDone: true,
    hideWhenDoneDelay: 200
  };

  let inputText = <Typist cursor={typistCursor}>test@mail.com</Typist>;
  if(state >= 6) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      inputText = <div className={classes.InputText}>Indtast din email her...</div>
    }, 1000)
  }

  const inputText = <Typist cursor={typistCursor}>test@mail.com</Typist>;

  const renderNextBubble = () => {
    const newState = state + 1;
    setState(newState);
    console.log('test state', state);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.chatWrapper}>

      <ChatBubble
        isReply={false}
        animationDelay={0}
        animationCallback={renderNextBubble}
        chatChoices={choices}
      >
        <p>Hvornår købte du din vare?</p>
      </ChatBubble>

      {state >= 1 ? (
        <ChatBubble
          isReply={true}
          animationDelay={0}
          animationCallback={renderNextBubble}
        >
          Under 2 år siden
        </ChatBubble>
      ) : null}

      {state >= 2 ? (
        <ChatBubble
          isReply={false}
          animationDelay={0}
          animationCallback={renderNextBubble}
          chatChoices={choices2}
        >
          <p>Er det under 6 måneder siden at du bestilte/modtog dit køb?</p>
        </ChatBubble>
      ) : null}

      {state >= 3 ? (
        <ScrollAnimation
          animateIn="fadeIn"
          duration={0.5}
          delay={-0.25}
          animateOnce={true}
          afterAnimatedIn={renderNextBubble}
        >
          <div className={classes.DotContainer}>
            <div className={classes.Dot}></div>
          </div>
        </ScrollAnimation>
      ) : null}
      {state >= 4 ? (
        <ScrollAnimation
          animateIn="fadeIn"
          duration={0.5}
          delay={-0.25}
          animateOnce={true}
          afterAnimatedIn={renderNextBubble}
        >
          <div className={classes.DotContainer}>
            <div className={classes.Dot}></div>
          </div>
        </ScrollAnimation>
      ) : null}
      {state >= 5 ? (
        <ScrollAnimation
          animateIn="fadeIn"
          duration={0.5}
          delay={-0.25}
          animateOnce={true}
          afterAnimatedIn={renderNextBubble}
        >
          <div className={classes.DotContainer}>
            <div className={classes.Dot}></div>
          </div>
        </ScrollAnimation>
      ) : null}

      {state >= 6 ? (
        <>
          <ChatBubble
            isReply={false}
            animationDelay={0}
            animationCallback={renderNextBubble}
          >
            <p style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Du er næsten færdig</p>
            <p>
              Skriv din email nedenunder, så har vi en mulighed for at sende
              klagen til dig
            </p>
            <p style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
              Dobbelttjek at du har skrevet den rigtige mail!
            </p>
          </ChatBubble>
          <div className={classes.EmailInput}>
            {setTimeout(() => {
              console.log('executing timeout');
              setShowInputText(true);
            }, 1000)}
            {showInputText ? (
              inputText
            ) : (
              <div className={classes.InputText}>Indtast din email her...</div>
            )}
          </div>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

**ChatBubble.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './ChatBubble.module.css';
import Typist from 'react-typist';
import ChatChoices from '../ChatChoices/ChatChoices';
import ScrollAnimation from 'react-animate-on-scroll';

const chatBubble = (props) => {
  const { isReply, animationDelay, animationCallback, chatChoices } = props;
  let text = props.children;

  const typistCursor = {
    hideWhenDone: true,
    hideWhenDoneDelay: 200
  };

  if (props.typist) {
    text = (
      <Typist cursor={typistCursor}>
        <Typist.Delay ms={600} />
        {props.children}
      </Typist>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ScrollAnimation
      animateIn="fadeIn"
      duration={1}
      delay={animationDelay}
      animateOnce={true}
      afterAnimatedIn={animationCallback}
    >
      <div
        className={`${classes.chatLine} ${
          isReply ? classes.chatLineWhite : classes.chatLineBlue
        }`}
      >
        <div
          className={`${
            isReply ? classes.chatBubbleBlue : classes.chatBubbleWhite
          } ${classes.chatBubble}`}
        >
          <div>{text}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {chatChoices ? <ChatChoices choices={chatChoices} /> : null}
    </ScrollAnimation>
  );
};

export default chatBubble;
```

**ChatChoices.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './ChatChoices.module.css';

const chatChoices = ({ choices }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.chatLine}>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        <p>VÆLG EN MULIGHED</p>
        <div className={classes.choicesWrapper}>
          {choices
            ? choices.map((choice) => (
                <div key={choice.text} className={classes.choice}>
                  {choice.text}
                </div>
              ))
            : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default chatChoices;
```

Comment: Is the the Typist component, if so, any reason you just don't use `<Typist.Delay ms={1000} />`?

Comment: @Keith yea, the reason i am not using that, is because I have to simultaneously remove the existing text when the delay is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSX, `{...}` outputs the result of the expression within it. (You're relying on this elsewhere, for instance `className={classes.InputText}`.) You're evaluating `setTimeout` in `{}`, which returns a timer handle, which is a number.

You shouldn't be using `setTimeout` in your JSX at all. Instead, just run it in the body of your component, **if** you really want it run every time your component is rendered:

```
const Chat = () => {

  const [showInputText, setShowInputText] = useState(false)

  const typistCursor = {
    hideWhenDone: true,
    hideWhenDoneDelay: 200,
  }

  const inputText = (<Typist cursor={typistCursor}>test@mail.com</Typist>)

  // *** Moved
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('executing timeout');
    setShowInputText(true);
  }, 1000)
  // ***

  return (
    <div className={classes.EmailInput}>
      {showInputText ? (inputText) : (<div className={classes.InputText}>Indtast din email her...</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const classes = {
    InputText: {
        color: "green"
    }
};

const Chat = () => {

  const [showInputText, setShowInputText] = useState(false)

  const typistCursor = {
    hideWhenDone: true,
    hideWhenDoneDelay: 200,
  }

  // *** Replaced Typist here just for demo purposes
  const inputText = (<div>test@mail.com</div>)

  // *** Moved
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('executing timeout');
    setShowInputText(true);
  }, 1000)
  // ***

  return (
    <div className={classes.EmailInput}>
      {showInputText ? (inputText) : (<div className={classes.InputText}>Indtast din email her...</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chat />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**But**, note that by making `setTimeout` unconditional, you'll keep doing it again and again even when `showInputText` is already `true`. If you only want to do it when it's `false`, add a branch:

```
const Chat = () => {

  const [showInputText, setShowInputText] = useState(false)

  const typistCursor = {
    hideWhenDone: true,
    hideWhenDoneDelay: 200,
  }

  const inputText = (<Typist cursor={typistCursor}>test@mail.com</Typist>)

  // *** Added `if`
  if (!showInputText) {
    // *** Moved
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('executing timeout');
      setShowInputText(true);
    }, 1000)
    // ***
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.EmailInput}>
      {showInputText ? (inputText) : (<div className={classes.InputText}>Indtast din email her...</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const classes = {
    InputText: {
        color: "green"
    }
};

const Chat = () => {

  const [showInputText, setShowInputText] = useState(false)

  const typistCursor = {
    hideWhenDone: true,
    hideWhenDoneDelay: 200,
  }

  // *** Replaced Typist here just for demo purposes
  const inputText = (<div>test@mail.com</div>)

  // *** Added `if`
  if (!showInputText) {
    // *** Moved
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('executing timeout');
      setShowInputText(true);
    }, 1000)
    // ***
  }
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.EmailInput}>
      {showInputText ? (inputText) : (<div className={classes.InputText}>Indtast din email her...</div>)}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chat />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

In a comment you've said you're worried about the timeout starting before the component is shown, and that the timeout should only start when `state >= 6`. To do that, use a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) callback with `state` (and `showInputText`) as dependencies, and set the timer if `!showInputText && state >= 6`:

```
// *** `useEffect` depending on `state` and `showInputText`
useEffect(() => {
  // You'll see this console log every time the component is rendered
  // with an updated `showInputText` or `state`
  console.log("useEffect callback called");
  // *** Added `if`
  if (!showInputText && state >= 6) {
    console.log("Setting timer");
    // *** Moved
    setTimeout(() => {
      // You'll only see this one when `showInputText` was falsy when
      // the `useEffect` callback was called just after rendering
      console.log('executing timeout');
      setShowInputText(true);
    }, 1000)
    // ***
  }
}, [showInputText, state]);
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const classes = {
    InputText: {
        color: "green"
    }
};

const Chat = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const [showInputText, setShowInputText] = useState(false)

  const typistCursor = {
    hideWhenDone: true,
    hideWhenDoneDelay: 200,
  }

  // *** Replaced Typist here just for demo purposes
  const inputText = (<div>test@mail.com</div>)

  // *** `useEffect` depending on `state` and `showInputText`
  useEffect(() => {
    // You'll see this console log every time the component is rendered
    // with an updated `showInputText` or `state`
    console.log("useEffect callback called");
    // *** Added `if`
    if (!showInputText && state >= 6) {
      console.log("Setting timer");
      // *** Moved
      setTimeout(() => {
        // You'll only see this one when `showInputText` was falsy when
        // the `useEffect` callback was called just after rendering
        console.log('executing timeout');
        setShowInputText(true);
      }, 1000)
      // ***
    }
  }, [showInputText, state]);
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.EmailInput}>
      {showInputText ? (inputText) : (<div className={classes.InputText}>Indtast din email her...</div>)}
      <input type="button" onClick={
          /* Just a really quick and dirty button to let us increment `state` */
          () => setState(s => s + 1)
          } value={`State: ${state} - Increment`} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chat />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, if your component may be re-rendered for some *other* reason than the `setShowInputText(true)` call above, you might want to cancel the timer to avoid outdated calls, via a cleanup function in the `useEffect` hook:

```
// *** `useEffect` depending on `state` and `showInputText`
useEffect(() => {
  // You'll see this console log every time the component is rendered
  // with an updated `showInputText` or `state`
  console.log("useEffect callback called");
  // *** Added `if`
  if (!showInputText && state >= 6) {
    console.log("Setting timer");
    // *** Moved
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      // You'll only see this one when `showInputText` was falsy when
      // the `useEffect` callback was called just after rendering
      console.log('executing timeout');
      setShowInputText(true);
    }, 1000)
    // ***
    // *** This is the cleanup function. It's a no-op if the timer has
    // already fired; if the timer hasn't fired, it prevents it firing
    // twice.
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}, [showInputText, state]);
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const classes = {
    InputText: {
        color: "green"
    }
};

const Chat = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const [showInputText, setShowInputText] = useState(false)

  const typistCursor = {
    hideWhenDone: true,
    hideWhenDoneDelay: 200,
  }

  // *** Replaced Typist here just for demo purposes
  const inputText = (<div>test@mail.com</div>)

  // *** `useEffect` depending on `state` and `showInputText`
  useEffect(() => {
    // You'll see this console log every time the component is rendered
    // with an updated `showInputText` or `state`
    console.log("useEffect callback called");
    // *** Added `if`
    if (!showInputText && state >= 6) {
      // *** Moved
      console.log("Setting timer");
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        // You'll only see this one when `showInputText` was falsy when
        // the `useEffect` callback was called just after rendering
        console.log('executing timeout');
        setShowInputText(true);
      }, 1000)
      // ***
      // *** This is the cleanup function. It's a no-op if the timer has
      // already fired; if the timer hasn't fired, it prevents it firing
      // twice.
      return () => {
        console.log("Clearing timer");
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    }
  }, [showInputText, state]);
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.EmailInput}>
      {showInputText ? (inputText) : (<div className={classes.InputText}>Indtast din email her...</div>)}
      <input type="button" onClick={
          /* Just a really quick and dirty button to let us increment `state` */
          () => setState(s => s + 1)
          } value={`State: ${state} - Increment`} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chat />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have included it in the post, but I did not think it would be relevant: The thing is, that the jsx in the render function is in itself already delayed through state, so I do not need to delay the render based on the render of the entire component, but only for this tiny bit. Pasted the full code here: https://pastebin.com/Md6nJBCj

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen - I don't understand your comment. In the code in the question, you're clearly rendering two different things based on `showInputText` (and not *delaying* rendering anything, unless you think in terms of delaying rendering the thing you only render when the flag is `true`). If you think more is pertinent to the question, please add it to the question. Questions and answers on SO must be self-contained, not reliant on off-site links. (Ideally, make it a full [mcve] using Stack Snippets like the above; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).)

Comment: Crowder - I have updated the original post with further explanation and code examples - i felt the SO tool was too complicated to use when i'm using several 3rd party libraries which don't all have a CDN.

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen - The basic issue I explained above is in that code too, I don't see why the solution doesn't apply. Don't do `{setTimeout(...)}` in your JSX. Do it (probably within an `if`) in your component function body.

Comment: Crowder - I mean yea, you technically answered the title of the question, and i will approve your answer for that. But the problem with the code you wrote, is that the if statement would be called immediately when the code is rendered, resulting in `showInputText` being true before the EmailInput is even rendered, which results in the placeholder text never being rendered (visibly) for the user. I assume this is how it would work, I haven't actually tested it yet. The thing to understand is that it takes many seconds from the component is first rendered until the input field should be.

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen - Please don't accept any answers that don't answer your question. :-) It wouldn't be set true prior to rendering because you have a one second delay there. But if you want to start that one second delay after rendering, use a `useEffect` callback. That won't be called until the component has been rendered and the DOM updated. I'll add a note about that to the answer.

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen - Done updating. Hope that helps!

Comment: I know about useEffect and other React hooks, but I think you are still misunderstanding the problem.  Either that, or I just have serious trouble understanding what you actually mean :-). The problem is not that i want the timeout to start after the component is rendered, the problem is that i want to start the timeout after the "input field" has been rendered when the state of the component is >= 6. https://pastebin.com/KVYSHGwF <- after this is rendered, the timeout should start.

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen - It would have helped if you'd said that above! Expecting people to read walls of code without calling out the important bits is problematic. That's easily done: Add `state` as a dependency on the `useEffect`, and only trigger it when `state >= 6` and `showInputText` is false.

Comment: Crowder, I just reread my post, and I'd say that I did say it "_The problem is that I need a timeout to occur when the 'input field' is rendered, since the user has to see the placeholder for a couple of seconds before the typing animation from Typist is triggered._"  - also i did not initially have walls of code, that was per your request.  I actually just got it working myself by creating a `DelayedRender` component: https://pastebin.com/pREUAY1L. But i think your solution is prettier and more efficient, so thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you add the solution to your post, I will accept it.